# I am new to C++ and get this error when using my pointer , any sugestions?

Tags: c++

> First-chance exception at 0x01204001 in ConsoleApplication2.exe:
>   0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCCCCCCCC.

```
#include "stdafx.h";

#include <iostream>;

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;



int main()
{
   char pause;

    int Max = 26;  // 27 indexes minus 1


    char* alpha[] = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E",
    "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K",
    "L", "M", "N", "O",
    "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T",
    "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z" };

//char* alpha(alpha1[26]);
//using for loop to print alphabet
    cout << "PRINTING CONTENTS OF ARRAY" << endl;
    cout << "===========================" << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i <= Max; i++) {
        cout << alpha[i]; 
    };

    cout << endl;

   cout << "\n Enter any key then press enter to continue: ";
   cin >> pause;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Run it with the debugger.

Comment: don't put a semicolon after the `#include`

Comment: `i <= Max; ` in the loop condition must be `i < Max; `. `Max` is not a valid array index.

Comment: Your array has 26 valid elements, not 27 as your comment claims.

Comment: By the way, in your instance, the expression `sizeof(alpha) / sizeof(alpha[0])` will give you the size of the array at compile time.  This eliminates any mismatches between your `#define` and the actual content of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Change the for loop to

```
for(int i = 0; i < Max; i++) {
    cout << alpha[i]; 
};
```

and you are good to go. You were indexing past the end of the array. Array indexes are 0-based. So you need to go from 0 to 25.